# BeginInvoke does not trigger

Tags: c#, .net

I have this script:

```
Action update = () =>
{
    dataGridMaterials.DataSource = null;

    dataGridMaterials.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    dataGridMaterials.DataSource = materials;

    dataGridMaterials.Refresh();
};

var invoke = dataGridMaterials.BeginInvoke(update);

if (invoke != null) dataGridMaterials.EndInvoke(invoke);
```

materials have many elements.
It should reload the DataGridView, but it doesn't. All I know is BeginInvoke is not calling the action.

Any idea o another way to update the DataGridView? (.NET Framework 4)

Comment: Not sure what `dataGridMaterials` is exactly, but are you missing a `dataGridMaterials.DataBind()`? Also why do you end it immediately?

Comment: Is the UI thread waiting for this piece of code to finish in a worker thread?

Comment: dataGridMaterials is a DataGridView control.

Answer (score 2):

`BeginInvoke` posts a message on the "UI thread". As soon as that thread is idle, it will pick up the message and process it.

If the code you shared runs on the UI thread, you might as well perform the action directly instead of using `BeginInvoke`.

If the code does not run on the UI thread, then the only reason for the action to not be ran that I can think of is that the UI thread is waiting for this code to finish, ie:

```
void MyMethodCalledOnUIThread()
{
    Action update = () =>
    {
        ...
    };

    ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback((o) =>
    {
        dataGridMaterials.EndInvoke(dataGridMaterials.BeginInvoke(update));
        mre.Set();
    }), null);

    mre.WaitOne();
}
```

This would cause the UI thread and the ThreadPool thread to wait for eachother, and the entire UI would stop responding.